# How to Prevent Nancy From Caching Views

Tags: c#, nancy

I've started testing out Nancy in self-host mode. So far, so good apart from one issue that's irking me: How do I prevent it from caching my views while developing?

I did notice a [comment](http://elegantcode.com/2011/06/26/nancy-view-cache-now-disabled-in-debug-mode/) that view caching is supposed to be disabled in Debug mode but it doesn't seem to be working for me - I have to restart my application whenever I make a change to the HTML.

I'm using Nancy 0.10 with the built-in super simple view engine and .html files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Caching *is* disabled by default in debug-mode. The only thing I can think of is that there might be a bug on the debug-mode detection while running in a self-host (i.e a non web-project).

Could you please try the following

- Make sure your are building in debug-mode and check the value of
  **StaticConfiguration.DisableCaches** and let me know if it is **true** or
  **false**
- Explicitly try setting **StaticConfiguration.DisableCaches** to
  **true** and see if it stops caching your view

If DisableCaches is true then it ignores to use the cache in the DefaultViewCache type https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy/ViewEngines/DefaultViewCache.cs#L30

Comment: Did you really mean _debugging_ in the beginning or should it be _caching_?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think something was screwy in my project settings and the DEBUG symbol wasn't being set.

Comment: Note that `StaticConfiguration.DisableCaches` was replaced by `StaticConfiguration.Caching.EnableRuntimeViewDiscovery` and `EnableRuntimeViewUpdates`.

Answer (score 3):

[TheCodeJunkies answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9534377/1767377) works for version 1.x of Nancy.

For 2.x of Nancy the `runtimeViewDiscovery` and `runtimeViewUpdates` properties handle if views are cached or not. This can be changed in your `NancyBootstrapper` class, like so:

```
public class NancyBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    public override void Configure(INancyEnvironment environment)
    {
        base.Configure(environment);
        environment.Views(runtimeViewDiscovery: true, runtimeViewUpdates: true);
    }
}
```