# Copy Razor-Views for Self-hosting NancyFx?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, host, nancy

I started out with a simple MVC-site using NancyFx with Razor-views (`.cshtml`) and `Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet`, using IIS Express.  Now I adapted the project to a self-hosting service using `Nancy.Hosting.Self` (and TopShelf).

However, to provide the Views, it seems I need to change their properties from `None` & `Do not copy` to `Content` & `Copy if newer`, so they are copied to `.\bin\Debug\`.

One consequence is that changes to the Views will not be shown/updated until a restart.  Even when working in [debug-mode, where caching is disabled by default](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/941).  I know this is just a minor annoyance, but still an annoyance, and it is nice to be able to try (cs)HTML-changes right away.  So I was wondering is there a way to fix this, e.g. to prevent having to set the files to `Copy if newer`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can provide a [custom root path](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/The-root-path) that looks directly at the views folder in your project.

Comment: I don't think it's very 'pretty', to have the root path to point to the parent directory (at least in debug mode).  But it may beat restarting after edit. (Or editing the copied files in `/bin/Debug' and moving the changes back to the source.)

Comment: i agree it's not pretty. i've made things uglier, but more helpful for clones, by writing out my root path location to a file from a build event (using a macro for the current working directory) and then reading in that file in an `#if DEBUG` statement. Ugly, but it works when the code isn't in a specific folder.

Comment: link is broken @jrsconfitto

Comment: Thanks @codetoshare, here's [a gist of my custom root path](https://gist.github.com/jrsconfitto/5782096) for development
(previous comment deleted)

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set these values:

```
#if DEBUG
  StaticConfiguration.Caching.EnableRuntimeViewDiscovery = true
  EnableRuntimeViewUpdates = true
#endif
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about debug-mode (I'll edit the question), and [in debug-mode caching is disabled by default](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9534377/422877). So I think the problem is caused by this copying.  Would there be a different setting where copy-setting is not necessary?

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  But in debug-mode caching is already **dis**-abled by default.  So this does not help me.

Comment: Try the jabbr.net/#/rooms/nancyfx room.

Comment: Thanks, they (re)advised [@Jugglingnutcase's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17090106/422877)