# How to work with Views without recompiling the application

Tags: razor, nancy

I'm trying to work with Nancy and Razor. The first thing I noticed is that the changes I make to the views while the application is running (self hosted) are not reflected until the application is restarted.

Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: it's probably because the application uses the razor files copied into  your /bin/Debug directory, so the ones you edit and save are not the ones the application uses. I haven't tried but I imagine it would pick up the changes if you set up a file watcher to copy the razor files into the bin/Debug directory on save.

Comment: I was able to figure it out too, but I was hoping that there was a way to change this behavior.

Comment: See [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981769/copy-razor-views-for-self-hosting-nancyfx/17090106?noredirect=1#comment24751687_17090106) for another way to do this.